# Transition between pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to set a transition between sections on a single page application, they are all on the same page but the other sections are set to display none so when I perform an event the display none is toggled for the section requested, now I don't just want the section to come in like that rather set a timeout that would make the section coming in not come in immediately but after like 5s, how can I achieve this, I already tried settimeout but it doesn't seem to work
Outline of problem

1. All sections except one have display none,
2. Event is performed on the page that doesn't have display none to bring in requested section and toggle display none
3. Upon request of page, the page transitions in or has a timeout, so the page doesn't swoop in immediately
   Code below,
   HTML

   ```
    <div class="main-container">
          <div class="page padding main" id="page-main">
            <div class="modal hidden">
              <button class="btn-close-modal">&times;</button>
              <h2 class="modal-header">Login to your account</h2>
              <form class="modal-form">
                <div>
                  <label for="">Username:</label>
                  <input type="text" />
                </div>
                <div>
                  <label for="">Password:</label>
                  <input type="text" />
                </div>
                <button class="btn header-button">Login &rarr;</button>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="overlay hidden"></div>
            <nav class="header-nav">
              <a href="#" class="header-img">
                <svg viewBox="0 0 256 256" class="header-svg">
                  <path
                    class="path"
                    d="m 15.625507,46.199537 55.767886,-32.030352 55.623047,32.281229 -0.14485,64.311586 0.14485,-64.311586 55.76788,-32.030352 55.62305,32.281229 -0.14485,64.311579 -55.76788,32.03036 -55.62305,-32.28123 55.62305,32.28123 -0.14485,64.31158 -55.76788,32.03035 L 70.958866,207.10393 71.103708,142.79235 126.87159,110.762 71.103708,142.79235 15.480664,110.51112 Z"
                    style="
                      fill: none;
                      stroke: #000;
                      stroke-width: 13;
                      stroke-linejoin: round;
                      stroke-linecap: round;
                    "
                  />
                </svg>
              </a>
              <button
                class="header-button login"
                type="button"
                data-page="page-login"
              >
                LOGIN
              </button>
            </nav>
            <div class="header-hero">
              <div class="circle1"></div>
              <div class="circle2"></div>
              <div class="header-text">
                <h1 class="header-text-description">
                  Make Banking Easy with Express
                </h1>
                <p class="header-text-texts">
                  Together we can make banking awesome!
                </p>
                <p class="header-text-texts">
                  Use our mobile app to your need today
                </p>
                <button class="header-button header-buttons" type="button">
                  <a href="">Services</a>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="header-image hide-for-desktop">
                <img src="./assets/hand.jpg" alt="" class="header-hand" />
                <button class="header-image-1">Transfer</button>
                <button class="header-image-2">Loan</button>
              </div>

     </div>
          <div class="page u-none" id="page-login">
            <nav>
              <a data-page="page-dashboard">User Settings</a>
              <a data-page="page-main">Logout</a>
            </nav>
            <h1>MAIN PAGE</h1>
            <form action="" name="login" method="" id="form-id" required>
              <label for="name">Name</label>
              <input type="text" id="name" />
              <label for="pin">Pin</label>
              <input type="text" id="pin" />
              <button type="submit" class="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="page u-none" id="page-signup">
            <nav>
              <a data-page="page-settings">User Settings</a>
              <a data-page="page-login">Logout</a>
            </nav>
            <h1>MAIN PAGE</h1>
            <form action="" name="login" method="" id="form-id" required>
              <label for="name">Name</label>
              <input type="text" id="name" />
              <label for="pin">Pin</label>
              <input type="text" id="pin" />
              <button type="submit" class="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
          </div>

          <div class="page u-none" id="page-dashboard">
            <nav>
              <a data-page="page-main">Back to Main</a>
              <a data-page="page-login">Logout</a>
            </nav>
            <h1>SETTINGS PAGE</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
   ```

CSS

```
 nav {
      display: flex;
    }
    nav a {
      color: #00f;
      padding: 5px 10px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    /* Utility classes */
    .u-none {
      display: none;
      opacity: 0;
      animation: 2s fadeIn forwards;
    }

@keyframes fadeIn {
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Javascript

```
const ELS_pages = document.querySelectorAll('.page');
const ELS_buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-page]');

console.log(ELS_pages);
console.log(ELS_buttons);
const submit = document.querySelector('.submit');
const goToPage = (id) => {
  ELS_pages.forEach((EL, i) => {
    // console.log(EL.id);
    console.log(`${i} : ${EL.id}`);
    console.log(id);
    // EL.classList.toggle("u-none", EL.id !== id);
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (EL.id === id) {
        EL.classList.remove('u-none');
      } else {
        EL.classList.add('u-none');
      }
    }, 20);
  });
};
// goToPage("page-main");
ELS_buttons.forEach((EL) =>
  EL.addEventListener('click', () => {
    goToPage(EL.dataset.page);
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a very basic implementation. It can be changed in many ways depending on your wanted effect. I had to modify your HTML because you had your pages nested on the main page and when the latter got hidden, it was hiding all the other pages too.

```js
const ELS_pages = document.querySelectorAll('.page');
const ELS_buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-page]');
const submit = document.querySelector('.submit');

const goToPage = (id) => {
  ELS_pages.forEach((EL, i) => {
    if (EL.id === id) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        EL.classList.remove('u-none');
      
        // THIS TIMEOUT IS IMPORTANT TO ALLOW BROWSER TO REPAINT AFTER CHANGING display PROPERTY. IF NOT, TRANSITION COULD NOT WORK.
        setTimeout(() => {
          EL.style.opacity = 1;
        }, 100);
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      EL.style.opacity = 0;
      
      setTimeout(() => {
        EL.classList.add('u-none');
      }, 1000);
    }
  });
};

ELS_buttons.forEach((EL) =>
  EL.addEventListener('click', () => {
    goToPage(EL.dataset.page);
  })
);

goToPage('page-main');
```

```css
nav {
    display: flex;
}

nav a {
    color: #00f;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.page {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.u-none {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="page padding main u-none" id="page-main">
        <div class="modal hidden">
            <button class="btn-close-modal">&times;</button>
            <h2 class="modal-header">Login to your account</h2>
            <form class="modal-form">
                <div>
                    <label for="input-username">Username:</label>
                    <input id="input-username" type="text"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="input-password">Password:</label>
                    <input id="input-password" type="text"/>
                </div>
                <button class="btn header-button">Login &rarr;</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        
        <div class="overlay hidden"></div>
        
        <nav class="header-nav">
            <a href="#" class="header-img">
                <svg viewBox="0 0 256 256" class="header-svg">
                    <path
                            class="path"
                            d="m 15.625507,46.199537 55.767886,-32.030352 55.623047,32.281229 -0.14485,64.311586 0.14485,-64.311586 55.76788,-32.030352 55.62305,32.281229 -0.14485,64.311579 -55.76788,32.03036 -55.62305,-32.28123 55.62305,32.28123 -0.14485,64.31158 -55.76788,32.03035 L 70.958866,207.10393 71.103708,142.79235 126.87159,110.762 71.103708,142.79235 15.480664,110.51112 Z"
                            style="
                   fill: none;
                   stroke: #000;
                   stroke-width: 13;
                   stroke-linejoin: round;
                   stroke-linecap: round;
                 "
                    />
                </svg>
            </a>
            <button
                    class="header-button login"
                    type="button"
                    data-page="page-login"
            >
                LOGIN
            </button>
        </nav>
        
        <div class="header-hero">
            <div class="circle1"></div>
            <div class="circle2"></div>
            <div class="header-text">
                <h1 class="header-text-description">
                    Make Banking Easy with Express
                </h1>
                <p class="header-text-texts">
                    Together we can make banking awesome!
                </p>
                <p class="header-text-texts">
                    Use our mobile app to your need today
                </p>
                <button class="header-button header-buttons" type="button">
                    <a href="">Services</a>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="header-image hide-for-desktop">
                <img src="./assets/hand.jpg" alt="" class="header-hand"/>
                <button class="header-image-1">Transfer</button>
                <button class="header-image-2">Loan</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="page u-none" id="page-login">
        <nav>
            <a data-page="page-dashboard">User Settings</a>
            <a data-page="page-main">Logout</a>
        </nav>
        <h1>MAIN PAGE 1</h1>
        <form action="" name="login" method="POST" id="form-1">
            <label for="name-1">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name-1" required/>
            <label for="pin-1">Pin</label>
            <input type="text" id="pin-1" required/>
            <button type="submit" class="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="page u-none" id="page-signup">
        <nav>
            <a data-page="page-settings">User Settings</a>
            <a data-page="page-login">Logout</a>
        </nav>
        <h1>MAIN PAGE 2</h1>
        <form action="" name="login" method="POST" id="form-id">
            <label for="name-2">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name-2" required/>
            <label for="pin-2">Pin</label>
            <input type="text" id="pin-2" required/>
            <button type="submit" class="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="page u-none" id="page-dashboard">
        <nav>
            <a data-page="page-main">Back to Main</a>
            <a data-page="page-login">Logout</a>
        </nav>
        <h1>SETTINGS PAGE</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fullpage.js`

This is simple and have variety settings. so check this https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullpage.js